# I want to distinct a specific column from a table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to get distinct column data from a table.
my code is below.
how can i make the season column distinct?

```
<div class="episodes">
    <?php
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $select=mysql_query("select * from data where name='$name'");
    while($show=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    { ?>
        <div class="episodes_data">
            <div class="t_s_pic">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="admin/photo/movieForsaken-2016-movie-Justin-Price-6-355x500.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="t_s_name"><h3><a href="">Game Of Thrones<br/>season<?php echo $show['season'];?></a></h3></div>
            <div class="t_s_download"><a href="">Download series</a></div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Give us some more details and show your desired output. Take a screenshot, do whatever it takes to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

for obtain distinct column you don't should use select *  by explicitally select the column  you need  eg:

```
 select distinct column1, column2, column3 from data where name='$name'
```